# Is specifier expansion performed with systemd `EnvironmentFile=`?

Tags: systemd

systemd.exec(5) [indicates](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=) the following for `Environment=`:

> Specifier expansion is performed, see the "Specifiers" section in systemd.unit(5).

systemd.exec(5) [indicates](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=) the following for `EnvironmentFile=`:

> Similar to `Environment=`

So, does systemd perform specifier expansion with `EnvironmentFile=`?

I expected so but my test under systemd 253.5 shows that no specifier expansion is performed with `EnvironmentFile=`.

### Test with `Environment=`:

Expansion is performed: `SECRET_FILE=/run/credentials/mycred1.service/mysecret`

```
[root@mymachine:~]# systemctl cat mycred1.service 
# /etc/systemd/system/mycred1.service
[Unit]

[Service]
Environment="LOCALE_ARCHIVE=/nix/store/5l0qzzkb3r3yxygdq3688fjcc18lwg3j-glibc-locales-2.37-8/lib/locale/locale-archive"
Environment="PATH=/nix/store/f11ibsj5vmqcy8ihfa8mzvpfs4af7cw5-coreutils-9.1/bin:/nix/store/jvh4fbqfxwwn162k5hb8ndc4h5555wfa-findutils-4.9.0/bin:/nix/store/rn5b13lbsslbvmmbqnqxdcagzqp4435w-gnugrep-3.7/bin:/nix/store/w64nwxs3r6cyqgy6ssxib5i2r6k8yfc2-gnused-4.9/bin:/nix/store/8lgs0dqh9ks1164fp4g14gq7w1ihjbf0-systemd-253.5/bin:/nix/store/f11ibsj5vmqcy8ihfa8mzvpfs4af7cw5-coreutils-9.1/sbin:/nix/store/jvh4fbqfxwwn162k5hb8ndc4h5555wfa-findutils-4.9.0/sbin:/nix/store/rn5b13lbsslbvmmbqnqxdcagzqp4435w-gnugrep-3.7/sbin:/nix/store/w64nwxs3r6cyqgy6ssxib5i2r6k8yfc2-gnused-4.9/sbin:/nix/store/8lgs0dqh9ks1164fp4g14gq7w1ihjbf0-systemd-253.5/sbin"
Environment="TZDIR=/nix/store/4faw3w020cjxvd1dnxhg73mi10wcxvpw-tzdata-2023c/share/zoneinfo"



DynamicUser=true
Environment=SECRET_FILE=%d/mysecret
ExecStart=/nix/store/wa8vcqsc5la5yxhazrq5rxmzy1y2igaj-unit-script-mycred1-start/bin/mycred1-start 
LoadCredential=mysecret:/etc/hosts


[root@mymachine:~]# cat /nix/store/wa8vcqsc5la5yxhazrq5rxmzy1y2igaj-unit-script-mycred1-start/bin/mycred1-start
#!/nix/store/7q1b1bsmxi91zci6g8714rcljl620y7f-bash-5.2-p15/bin/bash
set -e
echo SECRET_FILE=${SECRET_FILE}



[root@mymachine:~]# systemctl start mycred1.service 

[root@mymachine:~]# systemctl status mycred1.service 
○ mycred1.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mycred1.service; linked; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Jul 18 07:24:21 mymachine systemd[1]: Started mycred1.service.
Jul 18 07:24:21 mymachine mycred1-start[4110]: SECRET_FILE=/run/credentials/mycred1.service/mysecret
Jul 18 07:24:21 mymachine systemd[1]: mycred1.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

### Test with `EnvironmentFile=` (specifier in file content):

Expansion is not performed: `SECRET_FILE=%d/mysecret`

```
[root@mymachine:~]# systemctl cat mycred2.service 
# /etc/systemd/system/mycred2.service
[Unit]

[Service]
Environment="LOCALE_ARCHIVE=/nix/store/5l0qzzkb3r3yxygdq3688fjcc18lwg3j-glibc-locales-2.37-8/lib/locale/locale-archive"
Environment="PATH=/nix/store/f11ibsj5vmqcy8ihfa8mzvpfs4af7cw5-coreutils-9.1/bin:/nix/store/jvh4fbqfxwwn162k5hb8ndc4h5555wfa-findutils-4.9.0/bin:/nix/store/rn5b13lbsslbvmmbqnqxdcagzqp4435w-gnugrep-3.7/bin:/nix/store/w64nwxs3r6cyqgy6ssxib5i2r6k8yfc2-gnused-4.9/bin:/nix/store/8lgs0dqh9ks1164fp4g14gq7w1ihjbf0-systemd-253.5/bin:/nix/store/f11ibsj5vmqcy8ihfa8mzvpfs4af7cw5-coreutils-9.1/sbin:/nix/store/jvh4fbqfxwwn162k5hb8ndc4h5555wfa-findutils-4.9.0/sbin:/nix/store/rn5b13lbsslbvmmbqnqxdcagzqp4435w-gnugrep-3.7/sbin:/nix/store/w64nwxs3r6cyqgy6ssxib5i2r6k8yfc2-gnused-4.9/sbin:/nix/store/8lgs0dqh9ks1164fp4g14gq7w1ihjbf0-systemd-253.5/sbin"
Environment="TZDIR=/nix/store/4faw3w020cjxvd1dnxhg73mi10wcxvpw-tzdata-2023c/share/zoneinfo"



DynamicUser=true
EnvironmentFile=/nix/store/x2ybfrhf1v3g7saadggkfap1134hnkv2-mysecret
ExecStart=/nix/store/prpm62xlw5q9lnrrxjkn8wqc3l7m9njy-unit-script-mycred2-start/bin/mycred2-start 
LoadCredential=mysecret:/etc/hosts


[root@mymachine:~]# cat /nix/store/x2ybfrhf1v3g7saadggkfap1134hnkv2-mysecret
SECRET_FILE=%d/mysecret

[root@mymachine:~]# cat /nix/store/prpm62xlw5q9lnrrxjkn8wqc3l7m9njy-unit-script-mycred2-start/bin/mycred2-start
#!/nix/store/7q1b1bsmxi91zci6g8714rcljl620y7f-bash-5.2-p15/bin/bash
set -e
echo SECRET_FILE=${SECRET_FILE}



[root@mymachine:~]# systemctl start mycred2.service 

[root@mymachine:~]# systemctl status mycred2.service 
○ mycred2.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mycred2.service; linked; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Jul 18 07:25:24 mymachine systemd[1]: Started mycred2.service.
Jul 18 07:25:24 mymachine mycred2-start[4186]: SECRET_FILE=%d/mysecret
Jul 18 07:25:24 mymachine systemd[1]: mycred2.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

### Test with `EnvironmentFile=` (specifier in file path):

Expansion is not performed: `Failed to load environment files: No such file or directory`

```
[root@mymachine:~]# systemctl cat mycred3.service 
# /etc/systemd/system/mycred3.service
[Unit]

[Service]
Environment="LOCALE_ARCHIVE=/nix/store/5l0qzzkb3r3yxygdq3688fjcc18lwg3j-glibc-locales-2.37-8/lib/locale/locale-archive"
Environment="PATH=/nix/store/f11ibsj5vmqcy8ihfa8mzvpfs4af7cw5-coreutils-9.1/bin:/nix/store/jvh4fbqfxwwn162k5hb8ndc4h5555wfa-findutils-4.9.0/bin:/nix/store/rn5b13lbsslbvmmbqnqxdcagzqp4435w-gnugrep-3.7/bin:/nix/store/w64nwxs3r6cyqgy6ssxib5i2r6k8yfc2-gnused-4.9/bin:/nix/store/8lgs0dqh9ks1164fp4g14gq7w1ihjbf0-systemd-253.5/bin:/nix/store/f11ibsj5vmqcy8ihfa8mzvpfs4af7cw5-coreutils-9.1/sbin:/nix/store/jvh4fbqfxwwn162k5hb8ndc4h5555wfa-findutils-4.9.0/sbin:/nix/store/rn5b13lbsslbvmmbqnqxdcagzqp4435w-gnugrep-3.7/sbin:/nix/store/w64nwxs3r6cyqgy6ssxib5i2r6k8yfc2-gnused-4.9/sbin:/nix/store/8lgs0dqh9ks1164fp4g14gq7w1ihjbf0-systemd-253.5/sbin"
Environment="TZDIR=/nix/store/4faw3w020cjxvd1dnxhg73mi10wcxvpw-tzdata-2023c/share/zoneinfo"



EnvironmentFile=%d/myenv
ExecStart=/nix/store/779g5cfp6yq0lcpd4snmikxk1bkvfh4n-unit-script-mycred3-start/bin/mycred3-start 
LoadCredential=myenv:/etc/myenv


[root@mymachine:~]# l /etc/myenv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 23 2023-07-18 08:33:21 /etc/myenv

[root@mymachine:~]# cat /etc/myenv
SECRET_FILE=/etc/hosts

[root@mymachine:~]# cat /nix/store/779g5cfp6yq0lcpd4snmikxk1bkvfh4n-unit-script-mycred3-start/bin/mycred3-start
#!/nix/store/7q1b1bsmxi91zci6g8714rcljl620y7f-bash-5.2-p15/bin/bash
set -e
echo SECRET_FILE=${SECRET_FILE}



[root@mymachine:~]# systemctl start mycred3.service 
Job for mycred3.service failed because of unavailable resources or another system error.
See "systemctl status mycred3.service" and "journalctl -xeu mycred3.service" for details.

[root@mymachine:~]# systemctl status mycred3.service 
× mycred3.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mycred3.service; linked; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: resources)
         IP: 0B in, 0B out
        CPU: 0

Jul 18 08:34:59 mymachine systemd[1]: mycred3.service: Failed to load environment files: No such file or directory
Jul 18 08:34:59 mymachine systemd[1]: mycred3.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No such file or directory
Jul 18 08:34:59 mymachine systemd[1]: mycred3.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Jul 18 08:34:59 mymachine systemd[1]: Failed to start mycred3.service.
```

Comment: _Where_ specifically is not performed? In the name of the file? The contents of the file? Can you show your test?

Comment: In the content of the file. I have updated the question with some tests.

Comment: I don't think its implied or stated anywhere that systemd does template interpolation on the contents of anything other than systemd units. So if you due `EnvironmentFile=/some/%d/file`, that should work. I wouldn't expect it to go messing up the contents of files.

Comment: It seems the specifier expansion is not performed on the file path either. I updated the question again.

Comment: Your example doesn't actually show that. The error could be because `$CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY/myenv` doesn't exist at the time `EnvironmentFile`s are read. Try `systemctl show mycred3.service | grep -i EnvironmentFile` instead, you should see the expanded path there.

Comment: It returns `EnvironmentFiles=/run/credentials/mycred3.service/myenv (ignore_errors=no)`. Notice `EnvironmentFiles=` is in the plural form (if that is of any relevance). I also tested a variation of `mycred3.service` where I removed `EnvironmentFile=` and it shows that the file exist and the service can read its content and it can also source it to set the environment variables.

Comment: So you can see that the the specifier expansion is indeed done. "it shows that the file exist and the service can read its content", yes, but that's not my point. What I said was: "The error could be because `$CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY/myenv` doesn't exist **at the time `EnvironmentFile`s are read**."

Comment: Good point, so I guess systemd loads the credentials only after processing the `EnvironmentFile= `. Anyway, you answered my original question about the specifier expansion. Thank you! Perhaps, you could make it an answer (instead of comment) that I would accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifier expansions are done in `EnvironmentFile`s, but note that specifier expansions are done on the values passed to settings. So in the case of `EnvironmentFile`, the values are the file paths, *not* the file contents.

However, specifically for `%d`, it maybe the case that `EnvironmentFile`s are read before credentials are loaded, so `%d` might not be a useful specifier there. Inspecting the code, at [the point credentials are loaded](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v253/src/core/execute.c#L4683), environment variables from files are [already available](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v253/src/core/execute.c#L4241) - `setup_credentials()` is called from the `exec_child` function which has a `files_env` argument containing the environment variables from files.

There was [some discussion around making credentials available via the environment](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/19604), but Lennart Poettering thinks "that's not a safe thing since env vars are by default inherited down the tree, even when there are privilege transitions", so this might be a deliberate design choice to make the unsafe thing harder to do.